# How to add a second changelist_view to a django model

Tags: django, django-admin

The changelist_view is great for editing certain fields for many entries, so I thought about adding multiple views to my admin interface, each for different fields but I'm not really sure what would be the best way... did anybody do that before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have two differently configured Admin's for the same model, though there is a little tweaking need to make it work. Look the example here: http://www.mahner.org/posts/separating-staff-and-user-accounts-in-djangos-admin/. You wouldn't have to define different querysets for the two admin classes, but different options for the ModelAdmins!

Comment: i'll give it a try ... using proxying looks like a really quick (and quite ugly) hack :)